# Are statistics usable while running dbms_stats.gather_table_stats

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am working on oracle11g.

There's an external process running dbms_stats.gather_table_stats on a given table. More specifically it runs this code:

```
dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('STAGING','NEW_TRANSACTIONS',
      estimate_percent => DBMS_STATS.AUTO_SAMPLE_SIZE, 
      cascade=>true, method_opt=> 'FOR ALL INDEXED COLUMNS SIZE 1', 
      NO_INVALIDATE=>FALSE,DEGREE=>8);
```

The automated statistics collections do not work well on this table because the maintenance windows is at 6-8PM, but this table is entirely refreshed around 12PM causing the statistics to be stale. Hence, we gather the statistics ad-hoc.

Let's assume that gathering the statistics takes 60 seconds.

**What happens if a query runs on this table while statistics are being regenerated?**

Will the previous ( stale ) statistics be available until the new ones are generated? Or does oracle drops the statistics entirely when initiating dbms_stats.gather_table_stats ?

Let me rephrase this question this way: in the event of a query running in parallel to dbms_stats.gather_table_stats, which scenario is likely to happen:

1. will oracle use the prior / stale statistics to determine the execution plan? From my perspective this is acceptable as the statistical distribution of the data is relatively constant on most days, so the statistics might be stale from oracle's perspective but are still good enough in practice
2. no statistics are available to set up a proper execution plan, and the cost-based optimizer will fly blind when generating the execution plan

Comment: In my experience this is done in a transaction, so the usual transactional semantics for DML statements apply.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So I will assume that any given point of time, either the old or the new statistics will be available.